# Cognos 10: restrict the items displayed in a value prompt based on the criteria in another value prompt

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I'm trying to find a way to restrict the items displayed in a value prompt based on the criteria in another value prompt

I have a report where the row and column values are dynamically selected using radio button value prompt:

### Row Values

Nationality***
Domicile***
Fee Status***
Previous Institution
Sponsor

### Column Values

Academic Year
Level
Stage
Nationality***
Domicile***
Fee Status***
School
Department
Course

The starred values occur in both lists.

I'd like to be able to hide, for example, 'Nationality' from the Column Values if it has been selected in the Row Values.

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the column value prompt to cascade from the row prompt and set the Auto-Submit property on the row prompt to 'Yes'. Use the following filter in the query feeding the column prompt:

```
value <> ?rowParam?
```

...substituting the name of your data item for value and the name of your row parameter for ?rowParam?.

The query feeding the column prompt will output all values except the one selected in the row prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution but I've achived this using render variable. Essentially, I'm displaying a different prompt control based on a variable which looks at the other prompt control.

Would be keen to hear if anyone has neater solution!